# Finding the General form of linear operators that translate each vector of Euclidean space into an orthogonal one.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

> **Question**: Find the General form of linear operators that translate each vector of Euclidean space into an orthogonal one.

When I started solving this problem, I assumed that the operator matrix must be skew-symmetric and directly checked this for the $[3 \times 3]$ matrix. But how to prove that this works in Euclidean space for any dimension of the vector?

Comment: Can you be more precise in describing what the operator is supposed to do? Can you include your solution for the case $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Let the operator be given by the matrix A. Then if we apply this operator to the vector x, we get the vector y. Moreover, (x,y)=0.

Comment: You’re on the way... Write that inner product as $x^TAx=0$,

Comment: Note that in spaces of odd dimension, the operator will always have $0$ as one of its eigenvalues. Therefore, at least one vector will translate to $0$. This is related to the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem)